# angular form and routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form which is basically a search field where users type in a parameter and it redirects them to the proper page.

I am trying to pass in the argument in the form in a similar manner (in jade):

```
      form(name='searchForm', ng-href='#/item/{{ctrl.search}}')
        input(type='text', ng-model='ctrl.search')
```

Basically, I just want the route to change to `#/item/argument` when users press enter after having typed in the search field.

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I think you could set the `action` attribute on the form - this is how HTML forms traditionally send data to a URL.

However I would typically add a handler to the `ng-submit` directive on the form element instead. In the handler you would have something like this (remember to add the `$location` service to your controller):

**HTML**

```
form(ng-submit="ctrl.onSubmit($event)")
```

**JS (controller)**

```
this.onSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $location.url('item/' + this.search);
}
```

Comment: Might you be able to link to something that explains more what you mean by, "As an aside, you should be using the $scope service to inject data into the view from your controller - that's what it's there for" ?

Comment: Thanks - I've removed that comment. I believe it was the early days of the `controller as` syntax, which deprecated data injection using $scope. I must have been a bit slow on the uptake.

Answer (score 0):

> **Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VqoFVLBOG2i3YUkBJIJT?p=preview)**

First you need a dynamic route like

```
.when('/results/:item',
```

You search basically changes the location along with that parameter

```
$scope.doSearch = function() {
  $location.path('results/' + $scope.search);
}
```

Then pick up that routeParams and make a $http.get to your endpoint.

```
$http.get('endpoint/' + $routeParams.item)
```

Comment: I am using ui-router and when using $state.go I get the following error: could not resolve 'results/item' from (current state). How can I fix this?